# How do I loop my fancy Bash Dialog menu?

Tags: bash

So here is what I have, and I am very happy with what I have so far, but I do want to add a loop so when a command has been executed, ask for a "ENTER" strike and it will send you back to the menu...

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=(dialog --keep-tite --menu "Welcome to Ernie's Utility Menu v1.0:" 22 76 16)

options=(1  "Hide Connection"
         2  "Disconnect from VPN"
         3  "Status of Connection"
         4  "Update the system"
         5  "Clean up post update mess" 
         6  "Deep Clean (Trojans and malware)"
         7  "Speedometer (Bandwith Monitor)"
         8  "Bmon (Bandwith Monitor)"
         9  "Test Bandwith speed (up & down)"
         10 "Snow in the terminal"
        )

choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)

for choice in $choices 
    do    
        case $choice in
        1)
            expressvpn connect
            ;;
        2)
            expressvpn disconnect
            ;;
        3)
            expressvpn status && nmcli dev wifi
            ;;
        4)
            sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y #!//&& sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y not sure if I want to do this part....
            ;;
        5)
            sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo -k && exit
            ;;
        6)
            sudo chkrootkit -d && sudo rkhunter -c --rwo && sudo -k
            ;;
        7)
            speedometer -l  -r wlp2s0 -t lo -m $(( 1024 * 1024 * 3 / 2 ))
            ;;
        8)
            bmon
            ;;
        9)
            speedtest
            ;;
        10)
            ./snow.sh
            ;; 
    esac
done
```

Comment: One issue I can see with this loop and the answer below is that you don't have an exit.  I would make the Option 11 for Exit.  Then the case line would just be `11) exit;;` if you don't want to use Ctrl+C.

Comment: If you run this script, it has two options at the bottom, one is "OK"
The otherone is "CANCEL" which terminates the script.
Thank you for the info anyways!!!!
I might use it on another script!

EDIT: yes, you are right. "CANCEL" returns me to the menu, lol

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the script add:

```bsh
read -p "Hit enter to continue ..."
exec /bin/bash "$0" "$@"
```

the `exec` command will re-execute the script, re-using the current process.

Comment: SUPERB!!!!
Now my script is complete!!! you Glenn Jackman are a genius!!! 
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I'd rather work with an infinite loop in the script, then include an option in the menu to exit (command: `exit`, or `break`)

Answer (score 0):

SO, if someone is interested in recycle this menu...
This is what my final product looks like;

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=(dialog --keep-tite --menu "Welcome to Ernie's Utility Menu v1.0:" 22 76 16)

options=(1  "Hide Connection"
         2  "Disconnect from VPN"
         3  "Status of Connection"
         4  "Update the system"
         5  "Clean up post update mess" 
         6  "Deep Clean (Trojans and malware)"
         7  "Speedometer (Bandwith Monitor)"
         8  "Bmon (Bandwith Monitor)"
         9  "Test Bandwith speed (up & down)"
         10 "Snow in the terminal"
#         11 "exit"
        )

choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)

for choice in $choices 
    do    
        case $choice in
        1)
            expressvpn connect
            ;;
        2)
            expressvpn disconnect
            ;;
        3)
            expressvpn status && nmcli dev wifi
            ;;
        4)
            sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y #!//&& sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y not sure if I want to do this part....
            ;;
        5)
            sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo -k
            ;;
        6)
            sudo chkrootkit -d && sudo rkhunter -c --rwo && sudo -k
            ;;
        7)
            speedometer -l  -r wlp2s0 -t lo -m $(( 1024 * 1024 * 3 / 2 ))
            ;;
        8)
            bmon
            ;;
        9)
            speedtest
            ;;
        10)
            ./snow.sh
            ;;
         *)
            exit
      esac
read -p "Hit enter to continue ..."
exec /bin/bash "$0" "$@"
      done
```